# How to store series of values in python

Tags: python, excel, store

I just started with python a few days ago, anda i`m having some problems in finding a solution.

So, i've been using pycharm and i've downloaded some modules like *xlrd, xlwings, and xlwt* to analyse and format my excel data.

My maine goal is to find the highest values from a column that as positive and negative values, like for example:

```
a = [0, 0.34, 0.7, 0.88, 0.98, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, -0.1, -0.4, -0.6,-0.9, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.3,0.1, 0]
```

So my question is: there`s anyway to store the maximum values (0.98 and 0.9) and minimum value (-0.9) in a list or something??

Thank you for your patience and sorry for the grammar errors.

Comment: a simple solution, `srt = sorted(a)`, `(mx2, mx1), mn = str[-2:], srt[0]`, making sure you have cast the values to float

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `max(some_List)` function. It returns the maximum value in a list.

In the same way, you can use the `min(some_List)` function. It returns the minimum value of a list.

I am not aware of any function that returns the 2 maximum and the 2 minimum values of a list. You might have to build that yourself.

As for storing the maximum and minimum values in a list, you can do the following :

```
my_New_List = []              // declare a new list

my_New_List[0] = max(a)       // retreive the maximum value of your starting list and assign in to the index 0 of a new list.
my_New_List[1] = min(a)       //retreive the minimum value of your starting list and assign in to the index 1 of a new list.
```

I hope this helps you. Could you clarify a bit on what you're trying to do? And in what context you're trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To surmise the tools python allows you:

1. `sorted(l)` which takes a list like yours and returns a new list in descending order i.e., the max value is at index 0 or `l[0]`
2. `max(l)` which returns the maximum value
3. `min(l)` which returns the minimum value

For example, in order to get your highest `n` numbers from a list into a new list you only need do: `new_list = sorted(l)[0:n]`